# How do I rename a physical disk in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, intel-rst

I have two hdd that were part of a IRST raid 1 array. The pc failed and I have repurposed the drives. The drives are no longer involved in a raid array. The drives had three partitions, I've tossed them. What is interesting is that in some software like acronis backup, the name of the physical hdd is visible, and for these drives the name of the hard drive (not any partition) is INTEL RAID 1 VOLUME 1.0 (at least that's the name on one of them, not sure about the other from the original pair). Obviously IRST tagged them with that name.

I would like to name them something that is not mis-directive. Most hdd have a name from the make like ST4000DX001-1D2894. How can I rename the physical hdd?

This must have been answered but when I search via google the only answers I see that appear at all relevant are about storage spaces, which I don't use.

Answer (score 0):

- The UID is embedded in the drive firmware.
- This gets read by Windows and stored as a GUID device
- There is a friendly Name read and stored here that you can try to modify.
- I would suggest you use Procmon.,exe to trace this variable to see how it is used on boot and desktop.
  It will be located under this key
  My Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\

e.g. My Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SCSI\Disk&Ven_TOSHIBA&Prod_DT01ACA200\4&e937c7&0&050000

- Friendly name....
- Hardware ID

Comment: It's not exactly rocket science to rename a partition/volume. That is not what I am asking about. I state that clearly in the original post.

Comment: @TonyStewart you should edit your answer, so it answers the authors question

Comment: Thanks for that info Tony. On one pc, I can see the Intel drive name. On another, I don't see that name, so I'm not sure it appears in the registry at all. In both cases the hdd I'm testing is mounted via ext usb. The other oddity is that I don't see the enum of scsi entries change when I turn off the externally mounted hdd. F5 'refresh' seems to do nothing...even rebooted and list was the same. I don't get it.

Comment: I would check device mgr GUID for the drive and search registry. Doe s Off mean USB off or just HDD OFF and USB still ON.

Comment: I turned off the usb hhd dock device power in both cases (different pcs and different usb docking stations). Wouldn't we expect that a F5 should update the listing in the registry?

Comment: same OS? yes i guess use procmon to solve the mystery

Comment: No - the server that doesn't show the hdd is server 2012, and the other is win 7.

Comment: One thing that would help me figure is out is to correct my expectation re when/how the registry should show updates to the list of disks that are connected. On both machines, the list seems to just sit there whether I have the hdd on or off, regardless of the F5 key that is supposed to refresh the list...what should I expect?

Comment: find the answer up using Procmon, use search containing key for GUID of scsi or sata or USB drive

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make a follow up post here in case anyone runs into this thread and wonders how it turned out.

To summarize, acronis was showing a hdd name or id like INTEL RAID 1 VOLUME 1.0 for the two ex-raid 1 disks. I figured it had replaced the disk id which would have been something like ST4000DX001-1D2894 before. I can't explain why acronis showed that "INTEL RAID..." name above the volumes in the disk. But here is how things turned out.

I formatted one of the hdd and found that in acronis it's name had reverted to the name like ST4000DX001-1D2894. That was a big surprise.

The other drive I have not formatted and I can't mount it in the machine that has acronis (disk signature conflict). But I realized that I could probably see the disk id in device manager. And there it shows as the name like ST4000DX001-1D2894.

So somehow the acronis-visible name of "INTEL RAID 1 VOLUME 1.0" and the disk id like ST4000DX001-1D2894 co-exist. Both drives show the built in name like ST4000DX001-1D2894 in device manager, which is what I really care about. However acronis exposes the "INTEL RAID..." name/label remains a mystery but it doesn't matter to me at this point. If I need to use the remaining ex-raid disk in acronis I'll format it first, and that seems to have tossed the IRST name as part of the process.